# How to perform input validation with javax.ws.rs?

Tags: java, web-services, validation, jax-rs

I am implementing a REST API using `javax.ws.rs`. An implementation goal is to be as secure as possible, so every input should be validated.

For input validation, I am implementing a public class `ValidatingHttpRequest` that implements `HttpServletRequest`.

I could identify 11 methods which are even called, all the others now throw `UnsupportedOperationException`. However some of those methods handle things apparently used by the REST framework. For example my code does not care about headers, but `getHeaders` gets called. With a lot of reverse engineering I would be able to figure out what headers are used and should be validated, and of course I could do the validation. Possibly with introducing nonoptimal behaviours and maybe some bugs. And there are some similar aspects of the HTTP request.

But no one did this before, possibly someone who actually knows how the REST framework works? Or is it unnecessary, as the framework itself cannot be fooled?

So I am looking for a fully validating `HttpServletRequest` implementation, or a reasoning why it is unnecessary in this case. Of course I will validate the request body and parameters using the implementation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I am implementing a REST API using `javax.ws.rs`. [...] For input validation, I am implementing a public class `ValidatingHttpRequest` that implements `HttpServletRequest`.

You are missing the whole point of JAX-RS. In JAX-RS, you deal with annotated resource classes and methods, so you don't need to write "*low level*" Servlets.

> I am looking for a fully validating `HttpServletRequest` implementation, or a reasoning why it is unnecessary in this case.

You definitely *don't want* (and *don't need*) to write a Servlet for validation purposes.

JAX-RS implementations such as Jersey, RESTEasy and Apache CXF support [Bean Validation](http://beanvalidation.org/), an annotation-based API to validate Java Beans. You can validate pretty much everything you need, including request headers, parameters and entities.

Check the chapter 7 of the [JAX-RS specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxrs-2_0-fr-eval-spec/jsr339-jaxrs-2.0-final-spec.pdf), it describes how validation works. However, to integrate Bean Validation with JAX-RS implementations, you want to see the vendor-specific documentantion:

- [Bean Validation with Jersey](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html)
- [Bean Validation with RESTEasy](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.1.4.Final/userguide/html/Validation.html)
- [Bean Validation with Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/validationfeature.html)